# why signal function is not working using signal?

Tags: android, android-ndk

This code can't be executed. Signal is sent to the function via signal, but the code inside the function is not running.

```
void my_sigtrap(int sig) {
    LOGD("mtf----   why not working  ");
} 

void test_signal() {//SIGTRAP
    signal(SIGTRAP, my_sigtrap);
}
```

why my_sigtrap function not working?

Comment: While inside a signal handler, there are restrictions on which functions that you can safely call. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `signal()` does not send the signal, but installs your own signal handler so when that signal is received your function will be executed to handle it.  The signal is actually sent to the process using the `kill()` API (look up the details using `man 2 kill`).